# How to keep a process alive in visual C++

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli

So im writing a program that starts some executables from nearby directories, and one of its objectives is to keep these executables alive, so i did the following:

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
 Environment::CurrentDirectory = somedir;
 Process::Start("some.exe");
 Environment::CurrentDirectory = "../";
}
```

This button's objective is to start the process, **some.exe**, and then I use a **timer** triggered by a **checkbox** in order to start checking whether the process is still alive or not, and start it if not. I use a **checkbox** to keep this feature optional. So the **timer** code goes like this:

```
//this timer is triggered using a checkbox.
private: System::Void timer_Tick(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
 if () //Im stuck here,..
 {
 /*and here is stuff i do if the above 'if' statement 
 says the program is no longer running. In this case,
 I rerun the executable.*/
 Environment::CurrentDirectory = somedir;
 Process::Start("some.exe");
 Environment::CurrentDirectory = "../";
 }
}
```

and im stuck here, i searched around and found methods like **WaitForSingleObject()** or **OpenProcess + GetExitCodeProcess** but i was unable to understand the way they would be implemented.

Now what i need to do is use the **if** statement to check whether the process is alive or not, and do something about it, in this case, start it again. Im using the **timer** to repeat the check every 5 seconds.

I apologise if this question seems too noob-ish*, but im really struggling here, and the main reason for that is that im depending on examples that i find around to learn the code, and don't know a proper source for learning this language from a to z, properly. To be more precise, I don't know what im searching for exactly. Some help here will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want [`Process::HasExited`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.hasexited.aspx?cs-lang=cpp)

```
private: Process^ proc;

private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e)
{
    Environment::CurrentDirectory = somedir;
    this->proc = Process::Start("some.exe");
    Environment::CurrentDirectory = "../";
}

private: System::Void timer_Tick(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e)
{
    if (this->proc->HasExited)
    {
        Environment::CurrentDirectory = somedir;
        this->proc = Process::Start("some.exe");
        Environment::CurrentDirectory = "../";
    }
}
```

Other notes:

- You have common code between these two methods. Having a helper method `StartSomeDotExe()` would make sense.
- I doubt you'd want to start a second copy of `Some.exe` if it's already running. Therefore, I'd switch the helper method to `StartSomeDotExeIfNeeded()`, and call that from both event handlers.
- You don't have to change your application's working directory to run this other application from that directory. You can use [`ProcessStartInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.aspx?cs-lang=cpp) to set the working directory of the new process.
- You can forgo the timer entirely and use the [`Process::Exited`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exited.aspx?cs-lang=cpp) event. Subscribe to that event before you start the process, and you'll be called as soon as the process exits.

Comment: See the above post, I corrected a pair of typos after my original post: `.HasExited` should be `->HasExited`, because `Process` is a reference type, not a value type. For the same reason, `proc` should be declared as `Process^`, with a `^`.